# Why i am getting HTTP Status 301 on loading google using jquery?

Tags: jquery, load, http-status-code-301

I am trying to load the content of google.com in a div. I am using

```
$('#loadGoogleBtn').click(
    function(){   alert ( 'loading' );  
    $('.container').load('http://google.com');
        alert ( 'done' ); 
});
```

http://jsbin.com/uwopu4

But it is not working, instead it is giving me 301 HTTP status. [ Thanks to firebug :) ]. Why it is happening.

**Note** i am able to access google.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't make an XmlHttpRequest to a remote domain like this, it's blocked by the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Firefox chooses to present this as a 301, *how* the browser blocks it (read: chooses to enforce the policy) varies, but you'll always get an empty response.

This prevents you from doing something like:

```
$('.container').load('http://myBank.com');
```

and using my stored cookies, etc to login (also protected by the same cross-domain policy rules).